# Inner Join subselect as separate column

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables:
one is called "documents"
one is called "tags"
and one is called "documents_tags"

In table "document_tags" i have 3 columns:
ID, document_id, tag_id
which means that via this table muliple tags can be linked with multiple documents.

Now i want to put out all datasets of table "tags" and in each result-row i want to have a "1" if the tag is linked with the document of ID "3" (in table document_tags) and a "0" if not.

Is this possible in one single Query?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. If the matching row is not found, the columns in the `document` table will be `NULL`. You can use `IF(document.id IS NULL, "0", "1")` for the column you want.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a beginner and not able to find the solution ;-(

Comment: Can you give me a further tip. As written i want to generate the following query: SELECT ID, title, (Select * from documents_tags WHERE document_id=3 and tag_id=[Tag of corresponding result row] as linked FROM tags... Where to place the Left outer join and how can i refer what i wrote as "[Tag of corresponding result row]"? Sorry, my english is not so good...

Comment: Got it! This works for me:SELECT ID as t, bezeichnung, (SELECT ID from dokumente_tags WHERE dokument_id=".$doc_id." AND tag_id=t) as linked FROM tags. $doc_id is generated from PHP script

Comment: Left join is better than correlated subquery. See my answer

Comment: But to integrate left join correctly i'm not skilled enough i suppose. Can you give me the full query as example?

Comment: I put the full query in an answer an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, IF(dt.document_id, 0, 1) as linked
FROM tags AS t
LEFT JOIN documents_tags AS dt ON dt.tag_id = t.id AND dt.document_id = $doc_id
```